# MySQL search using partial string

Tags: mysql, performance, full-text-search

We have an ISAM table on MySQL that contains information about products. The table has about 3M rows (2GB) and we need to search a part based on partial string that may be included on three different fields (two are indexes).

To search for the rows that have the sub-strings `xyz` and `abc` and `efg`, we are currently using the following query:

```
SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM `TABLE`
WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ',field1,field2,field3,'') LIKE '%xyz%'
  AND CONCAT_WS(' ',field1,field2,field3,'') LIKE '%abc%'
  AND CONCAT_WS(' ',field1,field2,field3,'') LIKE '%efg%'
ORDER BY `field1`
```

Obviously, performance is terrible (15 sec). We are considering using full-text search index; any tips/input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The locate function most probably will be faster:

```
SELECT field1,field2,field3 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE 
(
locate('xyz',field1) > 0
or    locate('xyz',field2) > 0
or    locate('xyz',field3) > 0
)
and 
(
locate('efg',field1) > 0
or    locate('efg',field2) > 0
or    locate('efg',field3) > 0
)
ORDER BY field1
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. We benchmarked the locate and it's not doing better on our DB, on most tests; also, the Locate is supported only by MySQL, while the Like is part of the SQL standard.